# Reliable cross browser way of setting Status bar text

Tags: javascript, dom, statusbar

I've heard of **window.status** and that it can be used to control the browser's status bar text, but I would like to know if there are better or newer methods that can do the same, with most modern browsers. Also, is it possible to change the status text multiple times after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The feature you are looking for as been disabled for security reason.

Here is another solution to your problem.

You could create a DIV and put the position:fixed; at the bottom of the page, so people will always see it.

Comment: This is the closest you'll get, considering new browser default settings (look at Firefox, you'll see by default it doesn't allow JS to change or hide the status bar)

Answer (score 6):

For security reasons, most modern browsers disable status bar access by default.

Answer (score 5):

You'll find most modern browsers don't allow it any more as it was abused to hide link destinations.