# Asp.net HyperLink OnMouseOver

Tags: asp.net

How would I change or mask the URL when I hover over a hyperlink.

I was able to change the color but not the URL.

```
StatementsHyperlink.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.color=\"red\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would handle changing the styling with [CSS hover on hyperlinks](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp), you could set the text colour and the background to be the same shade of grey to mask the url.

Do you have an example effect you are looking for?

Comment: Would this hide the url in the status bar? If so, how?

Comment: No, you would need some javascript to do that but it is going to be different for each browser. Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/10468071/96505 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/876390/96505 for alternative

Comment: this.href = 'whatever' cause not only the text to change but also the URl. I am just trying to mask it in the status bar.