# How do I get Google Maps to display map-marker links in the status bar?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, hyperlink, google-maps-markers, statusbar, onmouseover

I am using `Google Maps API v3`, and have several map markers that link to different pages. When `onmouseover` the status bar is **not** displaying the url, however when the marker is clicked it **does** display the url loading text in the status bar.
It seems that my code is conflicting with the status bar in some way, or do you have to specify a property to show the status bar? Here is my code:

```
function initialize(mapInfo)
{       
    // object literal for map options
    var myOptions =
    {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 3), // coordinates for center of map
        zoom: 2, // smaller number --> zoom out
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID // ROADMAP, SATELLITE, TERRAIN, or HYBRID
    };

    // note: if the id has a dash in its' name, map instantiation doesn't work!
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    // MAP MARKERS instantiated here
    for(var i = 0; i < mapInfo.length; i++)
    {
        var link = mapInfo[i].link;
        var name = mapInfo[i].name;
        var lat = mapInfo[i].lat;
        var lng = mapInfo[i].lng;

        // object literal for each map marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            url: link,
            title: name,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map
        });

        // setting the link to each map marker here
        setLink(marker);

        // setting each map marker here
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
} // end of function initialize()

function setLink(mapMarker)
{
    // event listener for marker links added to each marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "click", function()
       {
             window.location.href = mapMarker.url; // obtaining the url from the object literal
       });
}
```

...I am getting the object-literal mapInfo (passed into the function initialize) from Ajax, parsed with JSON--just to clarify the mapInfo properties.
***********************************************************EDIT:* ******************************************************
Here is a solution, simply putting the link in an `infowindow` instead:

```
        // object literal for each map marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            //url: link,
            title: name,
            content: "<a href = " + link + ">" + name + "</a>",
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map
        });

        setWindow(map, marker);
function setWindow(map, mapMarker)
{
    // event listener for marker links added to each marker
        google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "click", function()
        {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
        {
            content: mapMarker.content
        });
                    infowindow.open(map, mapMarker);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Can't be done.

---

Your question is basically **"How do I set the text of the status bar to the link when I mouseover the marker?"**

So you need a mouseover handler to set the text, and a mouseout handler to put it back again.

```
function setLink(mapMarker)
{
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "click", function() {
        window.location.href = mapMarker.url;
       });
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "mouseover", function() {
        window.status = mapMarker.url;
        return true; // apparently this is necessary for window.status
       });
    google.maps.event.addListener(mapMarker, "mouseout", function() {
        window.status = '';
        return true;
       });
}
```

But see [Reliable cross browser way of setting Status bar text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876390/reliable-cross-browser-way-of-setting-status-bar-text) — you can't do it because browsers disable it. Once the url is loading, the browser itself displays it in the status bar as part of normal functionality.

One way which *would* work is to make the relevant marker image a link, because the browser's normal functionality would take over and display the url in the status bar. Unfortunately the API doesn't expose the various parts of a marker to make this possible either.

Comment: Wow, so this is not possible then... My only solution, which is close to what I wanted, is to change the map-marker event listener to display an `infowindow` with a link in it instead -- the url **is** then displayed in the status bar (I've added these details above).